# Different S3 Download Behavior Between the Console and CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have setup a cloudwatch log group to stream logs via kinesis & firehose into an s3 bucket, as gzip-ed files.

The gzip files are all tagged with some Metadata:

```
Content-Encoding     gzip
Content-Type         application/octet-stream
```

When I download one of the files directly from the browser console and unzip it I get the expected contents of a log file, namely json strings.  However, if I use the aws CLI to `cp` the file locally and unzip the contents then the file renders as binary at the terminal.

**What could be the cause in the difference in behavior between the AWS Console download button and the AWS CLI `s3 cp` command?**

I have already tried to specify various combinations of command line flags

```
aws s3 cp --content-encoding gzip --content-type "application/json"
aws s3 cp --content-encoding gzip --content-type "application/octet-stream"
aws s3 cp --content-encoding gzip --content-type "application/octet-stream" --sse-kms-key-id <keyArn>
```

But none of them have produced the positive result I get from using the Console in the browser.

**UPDATE**

The s3 cli version of the file is almost 10KB larger than the management console version.

Comment: I have tried to download the file with `cp` and everything went well - `aws s3 cp s3://${MY_BUCKET}/test.txt.gz test.txt.gz`

Comment: @AmitBaranes thank you for the response.  However, downloading is not the issue.  The problem is the encoding after the `gunzip` is applied locally (after downloading).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The firehose was setup to compress the contents of the message.  However, cloudwatch was already compressing the message as well.

When the browser downloads a file from S3 it automatically decompressed the first, of two, layers of compression.  Therefore, a second decompression resulted in the expected logs.

The CLI does not execute this automatic decompression.  So, decompressing the file still resulted in a compressed, binary, file.  A second decompression solved the problem.